# How to output list of objects to a single line with separators

Tags: powershell, text-formatting

New to PowerShell, great experience so far. How can I format the following cmd pipes to put the display to screen as a single line, with elements separated by `;` (to easily allow copy/paste into Outlook)

```
PS C:\Users\amrgro-dennem04> get-adgroupmember  -Identity "gbl-intel-l3-u" -Recursive|get-aduser -properties Mail|select-object Name

Name
 ----
AMRCVW-EDELSI
AMRMOP-REITES
amrmop-kruges
```

Basically, want the output to look like this:

```
AMRCVW-EDELSI;AMRMOP-REITES;amrmop-kruges
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
(Get-ADGroupMember "gbl-intel-l3-u" -Recursive| Get-ADUser -Properties Mail).Name -join ';'
```

Given that you don't need the `-Properties` parameter, because you're not using the `.Mail` property, you can simplify to:

```
(Get-ADGroupMember "gbl-intel-l3-u" -Recursive| Get-ADUser).Name -join ';'
```

Given that you're only accessing the `.Name` property and not really filtering by member *type*:

```
(Get-ADGroupMember "gbl-intel-l3-u" -Recursive).Name -join ';'
```

If you're using PSv5.1 or higher (on Windows), you can pipe the above commands to [`Set-Clipboard`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/set-clipboard) (`... | Set-Clipboard`) to copy the resulting text to the clipboard.
In lower PS versions, you can pipe to the external `clip.exe` utility instead (`... | clip`), but note that this invariably appends a line break and that you may run into encoding issues.

---

Note:

- In PSv3+, you can extract the property values of a collection's *elements* simply by using `.<propertyName>` on the *collection itself*.

  - A simplified example:
    `@( [pscustomobject] @{ one = '1a' }, [pscustomobject] @{ one = '1b' } ).one` yields array `@( '1a', '1b' )`
- `-join ';'` then joins the array of resulting property values with `;` as the separator to form a single output string.

Comment: @LotPings: Thanks, but `Out-Clipboard` is not a standard cmdlet. In PSv5.1+ (on Windows) you can use `Set-Clipboard`, however - answer updated.

Comment: @Fragtzack: Glad to hear it; you can pipe to `clip.exe` instead (answer updated).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help, it's a one liner with two commands chained together:

```
$test = get-adgroupmember  -Identity "gbl-intel-l3-u" -Recursive|get-aduser -properties Mail|select-object Name ; $test -join '; ';
```